# Non-standard urls with Yii urlManager

Tags: php, regex, url, yii, pcre

I need to use urls like `<controller>.<action>`, for example: api.wwwhost.com/index.php?r=**people.top**

So, I've tried to write pattern

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'caseSensitive'=>false,
    'useStrictParsing'=>true,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>.<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

but it does not work. As I know, symbol "." not included in "\w+".

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, when in "path" mode (`'urlFormat'=>'path'`), I cannot use the `index.php?r=people/top` style URLs. None of my `?r=` style URLs work when I am in `path` mode. Do you experience the same thing?

They DO when when I am "get" mode (`'urlFormat'=>'get'`), but in get mode the URL rules are not processed, and it appears to default to only use '/' for delimiters.

You code DID work for me when I used this style URL:

```
api.wwwhost.com/people.top
```

When "path" mode is set (i.e. `'urlFormat'=>'path'`), be sure to have your `.htaccess` file set up correctly to use it (hiding the index.php file). More info here in the [Yii Guide about URLs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url#hiding-x-23x).